# Linker error using VS 2015 RC, can't find symbol related to std::codecvt

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, stl, codecvt

I'm getting an STL-related link error, using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 RC (Version 14.0.22823.1 D14REL)

I'm linking a C++ DLL and successfully using many functions from the STL, but it can't find stuff related to std::codecvt:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class std::locale::id std::codecvt<char32_t,char,struct _Mbstatet>::id" (__imp_?id@?$codecvt@_UDU_Mbstatet@@@std@@2V0locale@2@A)
```

The source code reference causing this issue:

```
std::wstring_convert< std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t > convert;
```

My code generation is for multithread dll,  and I have verified through verbose linking that MSVCPRT.lib is being searched  at link time.

Any ideas ?

Comment: An update: Microsoft replied about this on MSDN (known issue): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f40dcd8-c67f-4eba-9134-a19b9178e481/vs-2015-rc-linker-stdcodecvt-error?forum=vcgeneral

Answer (score 3):

To clarify the issue and the solution: Microsoft acknowledged that `std::codecvt` is not built against the `char32_t` in std library provided with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 RC. The workaround is to use the `unsigned int` or the `__int32` types:

```
    std::wstring_convert< std::codecvt_utf8<unsigned int>, unsigned int > convert;
```

or

```
    std::wstring_convert< std::codecvt_utf8<__int32>, __int32 > convert;
```

instead of

```
    std::wstring_convert< std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t > convert;
```

Comment: This workaround works but it induces the issue that your basic_string also has to be based on unsigned int. This is just hell.